# Javascript: look for xpath inside element

Tags: javascript, dom

I get all the  elements via the xpath below. I want to look inside each TD, and search for another xpath inside each TD. I am not sure if the below approach works but this is something I'd like to achieve. I know you can do //td//a but I want to know how I programmatically search each element for more xpaths.

```
 var tds = document.evaluate('//td', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

 for (++index < tds.snapshotLength){
  //this link may or may not exist
  var link = document.evaluate('//a', tds[index].document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its sensible to define two helper functions that do the heavy lifting and return results that are easy to work with:

```
function selectNodes(path, contextNode) {
    var result, item, nodes = [];

    result = document.evaluate(path, contextNode || document, null, 
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

    while ( item = result.iterateNext() ) nodes.push(item);

    return nodes;
}

function selectSingleNode(path, contextNode) {
    return selectNodes(path, contextNode)[0];
}
```

Now using XPath becomes straight-forward:

```
var tds = selectNodes('//td'), i, a;

for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    a = selectSingleNode('.//a', tds[i]);
    console.log(a.href);
}
```

Note the relative path (`'.//a'`). You need to use relative paths when you want correct results with a context node - a plain `//` always starts at the document root.

Comment: yeah I discovered the adding `.` before the xpath, otherwise it wouldn't look in the right contextNode.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine, but your `for` syntax is incorrect and you need to use `snapshotItem` to access the results of tds:

```
var tds = document.evaluate('//td', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

var i;
for (i=0; i < tds.snapshotLength; i++) {
     var link = document.evaluate('//a', tds.snapshotItem(i), null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
     if(link.snapshotLength) {
         console.log(link.snapshotItem(0));
     }
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zybhupxf/)

Comment: I agree with this answer that the OP has an **incorrect `for`-loop**, and an **incorrect way of accessing the `snapshotItem(0)`**, which you fixed. However I think this answer is still wrong; (see JSFiddle below) note if I add two <td> to your markup (instead of one), and in each `<td><a>` I put different text, then I log `innerText`, **the console logs the same text twice** (it finds the same element twice because it searches from root `//a`).  http://jsfiddle.net/wbkgq8zh/ The key is to use a relative path `.//a` as shown in the accepted answer.